# Posting JSON to RESTful through formParam with JAX-RS results in "Unsupported Media Type"

Tags: java, json, rest

**I am Posting JSON object to RESTful service through a HTML page in Text Area i.e using FormParam in RESTful POST service.
I used all required annotations to the POJO class "@XmlRoolElement" ,
and @Consumes and @Produces value  as "APPLICATION_JSON"**

webservice takes arguments in @FormParam as String datatype and return the String

other POJO class of Singer with @XmlRootElement annotation

and HTML page contains a form textarea naming "song"
 and a submit botton and method as = "post"

and web.xml as

Answer (score 3):

When you do an HTTP POST through a HTML file/page opened in a browser, the content-type is url-encoded. So the @Consumes annotation should look like this:

```
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject;
.
.
.
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    public String postData(@FormParam("textAreaName") JSONObject jsono){
.
.
```